# Alternative Explanation of Quantum Double Slit Experiment with Different Polarizing Filter Over Each Slit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

I recall reading that if you put a parallel polarizing filter over one slit and a perpendicularly polarizing filter over the other slit, and send a singe photon to the slits, then the two waves that emerge from the slits do not interfere. The explanation was that the filters provided a "which-way" tagging of the photon and so, if that information is known, there can be no interference because the photon could only have gone through one slit.

Suppose the photon is in a pure state before reaching the slits. I think another explanation might be:

one emergent wave is tensor multiplied by one eigenstate of polarization and the other emergent wave is tensor multiplied by a different eigenstate of polarization.

When the two tensor products are added, we get a state vector (representing the joint polarization and position states) where each state of that state vector is described by a single wave.

Therefore, when probabilities are calculated, there is no cross-term and no interference.

So, in this interpretation, there are no interference patterns, but the wave goes through both slits, unlike the information interpretation where it goes through only one.

What do you think?

(Note, the answer below was for a different theory, where I thought the two emergent waves were part of a mixed state and therefore did not add (and interfere) for that reason. I no longer think that and, instead, think the above.)

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't change an existing question with an existing answer to invalidate the existing answer. The site lists questions, its not a list of askers with the questions always changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *"mixed states do not interfere"* you have to be using the meaning of mixed state that is equivalent to saying the light is incoherent. But passing through slits won't make coherent light incoherent.

More over, if you rotate one of the polarizers so that it is not quite 90 degrees from the other you expect to recover partial interference fringes (the argument is perhaps clearest in the classical description of the system, but both description must work in limit of a lot of light), and those fringes should increase in strength as the polarizers are brought more and more into alignment.

Your suggestion would not recover this behavior.

Experimentally this behavior is easier to test with a inter-ferometer (a Michelson device would work nicely) than with a two slit arrangement.